# What is wrong with this Javascript? shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html, external, shopping-cart

There is something in this javascript or html which is is allowing the checkboxes to be ticked but for not even half a second. (I need the checks to stay there!) I also need the additems function to work

```
var computer = new Array();

computer[0] = "10001, Nvidia Geforce GTX 690, 1200";
computer[1] = "10002, Raedon HD 7950, 450";
computer[2] = "20001, Ivy Bridge i7 3770, 400";
computer[3] = "20002, Ivy Bridge i7 3770k, 420";
computer[4] = "20003, Sandy Bridge i7 2700k, 340";
computer[5] = "20004, Bulldozer FX-8150, 270";
computer[6] = "30001, Antec eleven-hundred, 120";
computer[7] = "30002, Coolermaster HAF-X, 170";
computer[8] = "30003, Antec three-hundred, 50";
computer[9] = "30004, Corsair 550D, 160";
computer[10] = "40001, INTEL-ASrock fatal1ty Z77 Professional Motherboard, 250";
computer[11] = "40002, INTEL-ASrock Z77 extreme9 Motherboard, 350";
computer[12] = "40003, AMD-ASrock fatal1ty 990FX Professional Motherboard, 240";
computer[13] = "40004, AMD-ASUS Sabertooth 990FX Motherboard, 260";
```

Check all checkboxes function

```
function check() { 

var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'text')  {
        inputs[x].value = 1;
    } else {
        inputs[x].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

Uncheck all checkboxes function

```
function uncheck() { 

var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'text')  {
        inputs[x].value = 0;
    } else {
        inputs[x].checked = false;
    }
}
}
```

add checked items to cart

```
function addItems() { 
var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var rightSide = document.getElementById('table_container_right');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementByTagName('input');
var totalPrice = 0;
var basketTable = "<h3>My Basket:</h3><table><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>price</th><th>Sub-total</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[x].checked == true)  {
        var quantity = ParseFloat(inputs[x+1).value);
        var itemName = computer[x/2].split(",")[1];
        var itemPrice = parseFloat(computer[x/2].split(",")[2])
        var itemTotal = parseFloat(quantity*itemPrice);
        totalPrice += itemTotal;
        basketTable += "<tr><td>"+itemName+"</td><td>"+quantity+"</td><td>$"+itemPrice+"</td><td>$"+itemTotal+"</td></tr>";
    }
}
basketTable +=" <tr><td> colspan='3'><b>Total:</b></td><td><b>$"+totalPrice+"</b></td></tr></tbody><table>";
rightsSide.innerHTML = basketTable;
}
```

update quantity to 1 when item is checked

```
function updateQty(id)  {

var targetRow = document.getElementById(id);
var qtyBox = targetRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
if (qtyBox.value == 0)  {
    qtyBox.value = 1;
} else {
    qtyBox.value = 0;
}
}
```

Here's the HTML as requested

```
    <form name="myForm" action="index.html" method="post">

        <div id="table_container_left">

                    <button onclick="check();">Select All</button>

                    <button onclick="uncheck();">Unselect All</button>

                    <button onclick="addItems();">Add Items</button>

            <table>

                <thead>

                        <th><u>Item Code</u></th>

                        <th><u>Item</u></th>

                        <th><u>Qty</u></th>

                        <th><u>Price</u></th>

                </thead>

                <tbody>



<script type="text/javascript">

for(x=0; x<=computer.length-1; x++) {

document.write("<tr id='"+x+"'><td><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='"+x+"'     onclick='updateQty('"+x+"');'/> "+computer[x].split(",")[0]+"</label></td><td>"+computer[x].split    (",")[1]+"</td><td> <input name='qty' id='qty' type='textbox' value='0' onchange='qtychange    ('"+x+"');'/></td><td>$"+computer[x].split(",")[2]+"</td></tr>");

}

</script>







                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>



        <div id="table_container_right">

            <table id="shoppingBasket">













                    <input name='selectAll' type='button' value='Select All' onclick="itemSelected();"/>

                    <input name='clearAll' type='button' value='Clear All' onclick=""/>

                    <input name='removeItem(s)' type='button' value='Remove Item(s)' />

                    <input name='sortItemCode' type='button' value='Sort by Item Code' disabled='disabled' />

                    <input name='sortPrice' type='button' value='Sort by Price' disabled='disabled' />

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>



</div>



</form>
```

Comment: What should happen, whats actually do happens? Where come the variables computer and selectd from? With the given information an answer is impossible!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i = 0` rather than `var i = 0`, which will introduce a global variable. This could be a problem if you're writing similar code elsewhere.

Your `if`-statements are not statements at all. They look like pseudo-code. You're also comparing with `=` rather than `==`, which will cause an assignment rather than a condition, even if you fix up your syntax.

You are not properly indenting your code, which will make you much more prone to introduce new errors.

These are the general issues I notice immediately. Of course, heaps of things *could* be wrong with this code. `fields` might not be an array, `computer` and `selected` might not match the size of `fields`, etc.

If you have any specific problem, please describe that, and we may be able to address it.

Comment: sadly this didn't fix my issue.

Comment: then you should look into describing your issue.

Comment: @DavidHedlund You are wrong about iteration, it will iterate through all fields because his condition is <=.

Comment: @x64igor: quite right! didn't notice the `<=` operator. what an inconvenient way of saying `< fields.length`. oh well. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS syntax is way off, this is what it should look like

```
function addItems(field) {
    for (i = 0; i <= field.length-1; i++) 
    {
        if (field[i].checked == true)
        {
            if (computer[i]!=null) { 
                selected[i] = computer[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Half of your if statements are missing parentheses, that's some basic wrongfulness.

I don't know what and where should any of the variables be, but here is my best shot:

```
function addItems(field) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        if (field[i].checked === true) {
            if (computer[i] !== null) { 
                selected[i] = computer[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```