# what is wrong with my javascript code? (external file) (simplify would be awesome too)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, external

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is wrong with this Javascript? shopping cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517129/what-is-wrong-with-this-javascript-shopping-cart)

There is something in this javascript which is not allowing it to work at all. 
A simplify would be awesome too :)

```
var computer = new Array();

computer[0] = "10001, Nvidia Geforce GTX 690, 1200";
computer[1] = "10002, Raedon HD 7950, 450";
computer[2] = "20001, Ivy Bridge i7 3770, 400";
computer[3] = "20002, Ivy Bridge i7 3770k, 420";
computer[4] = "20003, Sandy Bridge i7 2700k, 340";
computer[5] = "20004, Bulldozer FX-8150, 270";
computer[6] = "30001, Antec eleven-hundred, 120";
computer[7] = "30002, Coolermaster HAF-X, 170";
computer[8] = "30003, Antec three-hundred, 50";
computer[9] = "30004, Corsair 550D, 160";
computer[10] = "40001, INTEL-ASrock fatal1ty Z77 Professional Motherboard, 250";
computer[11] = "40002, INTEL-ASrock Z77 extreme9 Motherboard, 350";
computer[12] = "40003, AMD-ASrock fatal1ty 990FX Professional Motherboard, 240";
computer[13] = "40004, AMD-ASUS Sabertooth 990FX Motherboard, 260";
```

Check all checkboxes function

```
function check() { 

var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'text')  {
        inputs[x].value = 1;
    } else {
        inputs[x].checked = true;
    }
}
}
```

Uncheck all checkboxes function

```
function uncheck() { 

var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'text')  {
        inputs[x].value = 0;
    } else {
        inputs[x].checked = false;
    }
}
}
```

add checked items to cart

```
function addItems() { 
var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
var rightSide = document.getElementById('table_container_right');
var inputs = leftSide.getElementByTagName('input');
var totalPrice = 0;
var basketTable = "<h3>My Basket:</h3><table><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>price</th><th>Sub-total</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for (x=0; x<=inputs.length-1; x++)  {
    if(inputs[x].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[x].checked == true)  {
        var quantity = ParseFloat(inputs[x+1).value);
        var itemName = computer[x/2].split(",")[1];
        var itemPrice = parseFloat(computer[x/2].split(",")[2])
        var itemTotal = parseFloat(quantity*itemPrice);
        totalPrice += itemTotal;
        basketTable += "<tr><td>"+itemName+"</td><td>"+quantity+"</td><td>$"+itemPrice+"</td><td>$"+itemTotal+"</td></tr>";
    }
}
basketTable +=" <tr><td> colspan='3'><b>Total:</b></td><td><b>$"+totalPrice+"</b></td></tr></tbody><table>";
rightsSide.innerHTML = basketTable;
}
```

update quantity to 1 when item is checked

```
function updateQty(id)  {

var targetRow = document.getElementById(id);
var qtyBox = targetRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
if (qtyBox.value == 0)  {
    qtyBox.value = 1;
} else {
    qtyBox.value = 0;
}
}
```

Here's the HTML as requested

```
    <form name="myForm" action="index.html" method="post">

        <div id="table_container_left">

                    <button onclick="check();">Select All</button>

                    <button onclick="uncheck();">Unselect All</button>

                    <button onclick="addItems();">Add Items</button>

            <table>

                <thead>

                        <th><u>Item Code</u></th>

                        <th><u>Item</u></th>

                        <th><u>Qty</u></th>

                        <th><u>Price</u></th>

                </thead>

                <tbody>



<script type="text/javascript">

for(x=0; x<=computer.length-1; x++) {

document.write("<tr id='"+x+"'><td><label><input type='checkbox' name='item' value='"+x+"'     onclick='updateQty('"+x+"');'/> "+computer[x].split(",")[0]+"</label></td><td>"+computer[x].split    (",")[1]+"</td><td> <input name='qty' id='qty' type='textbox' value='0' onchange='qtychange    ('"+x+"');'/></td><td>$"+computer[x].split(",")[2]+"</td></tr>");

}

</script>







                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>



        <div id="table_container_right">

            <table id="shoppingBasket">













                    <input name='selectAll' type='button' value='Select All' onclick="itemSelected();"/>

                    <input name='clearAll' type='button' value='Clear All' onclick=""/>

                    <input name='removeItem(s)' type='button' value='Remove Item(s)' />

                    <input name='sortItemCode' type='button' value='Sort by Item Code' disabled='disabled' />

                    <input name='sortPrice' type='button' value='Sort by Price' disabled='disabled' />

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>



</div>



</form>
```

Comment: Yeah? What's it supposed to do? What does it actually do? Any reason you're not just using immediate array initialization?

Comment: It would be easier to debug if we had the page in its entirety.

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem is (and it'd be hard to say without seeing the HTML as well), but using jQuery would save you at least half of this code. Seriously, it's a huge time saver; you should try it.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you look in your browser error console to see what error is reported?

Comment: I've added the HTML, what it's supposed to do is check all the checkboxes when the check all button is clicked. uncheck them all when the uncheck all button is clicked. and if the add items button is clicked it puts the checked items onto the right side of the page.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) javascript.js:55
Uncaught ReferenceError: computer is not defined index.html:48
Uncaught ReferenceError: selected is not defined

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }  when checking a checkbox manually.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes, which may or may not fix the problem if applied:

- There's a `ParseFloat` instead of a `parseFloat`,
- You often reference attributes as if they were integers, although they should be strings,
- There's a `computer[x/2]` which might result in a decimal array index,
- Variables are repeatedly declared within the for loop,
- `innerHTML` is used instead of the DOM.

Comment: I really have no idea what any of that means... I'm trying to learn Javascript and i've been doing this for 2 days =/

Comment: Well your call to the function `ParseFloat` is bad: it should be `parseFloat`, first letter lowercase. You should expect all HTML attributes to be a string; that is, things like `htmltag.value + 3` won't work, and you should instead use `parseFloat(htmltag.value) + 3`. For `computer[x/2]`, what element would you get if `x=5`?

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer.)

Here's one simplification, with at least two caveats:

1. Poorly-named function, since it does something other than simply setting checkboxes.
2. I'd recommend using a JS framework that simplifies DOM manipulation.

```js
function check() {
    setChecks(false);
}

function uncheck() {
    setChecks(true);
}

function setChecks(checked) {
    var leftSide = document.getElementById('table_container_left');
    var inputs = leftSide.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var textValue = checked ? "1" : "0";
    var x;

    for (x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++)  {
        if (inputs[x].type == 'text')  {
            inputs[x].value = textValue;
        } else {
            inputs[x].checked = checked;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd consider using immediate array initialization and objects. Also, the object holding the computers should be called that–`computers`. It's not a `computer`. It's a collection of them; plural.

```
var computers = [
  { id: "10001", name: "Nvidia Geforce GTX 690", price: 1200 },
  { id: "10002", name: "Raedon HD 7950", price: 450 },
  // ...
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Give you're using arrays, why not go whole-hog and REALLY use them?

```
computer[0] = [10001, "blah blah blah"];
computer[1] = [10002, "foo bar baz"];
```

and so on? It's like you're buying a fancy cabinet and then using it as a paper weight.

Comment: Not really an answer, though perhaps constructive.

Comment: Has nothing to do with answering the question.  Could be a comment, I suppose.